# Are lottery winnings taxed based on the ticket date or the redemption date?

Tags: united-states, lottery

Suppose I purchase a lottery ticket today (Dec 14, 2015) and win $25K. If I wait a few weeks and redeem the ticket after Jan 1, are the taxes due based on income in this year (2015) or next year (2016)? Perhaps the answer is simply when the money is received, regardless of ticket or redemption date? Could the answer vary for Fed vs State?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on when you can get the money, not when you know that you won or when you choose to take the ticket in.  If you can present your ticket this year and get paid this year, the taxes are due this year, whether or not you actually choose to claim the prize this year.  If you cannot receive payment until next year, then taxes will be due next year.  This is "constructive receipt," which applies to most individual tax situations.

This assumes that you chose to receive a lump sum.  If you get installments, then your taxes would be due as the installments are available, but the constructive receipt still applies.

Comment: Ah, just read up on "constructive receipt". Appears to both make sense and be crazy at the same time for the lotto case. One would expect that if it is reported in one year, that would be the year it would be paid. Alas it is not.  >.<

Comment: @Brick. Interesting. So how is "can" determined? If I misplaced the ticket until next year, or was out of the country on vacation, (or fill in your favorite excuse), does that mean I still *could* have gotten the money?

Comment: If the only thing preventing you from using the money is a voluntary action on your part then you have constructive receipt. The definition is kind of long for a comment, but you can easily find it by searching for "constructive receipt." There's also court cases specifically on the subject of lottery winners, so the functional definition has been challenged. When you win, you can afford to pay lawyers to fight for the definition that you want. :)

Comment: paying lawyers is not what I had in mind to do with my lottery winnings!

Comment: I just did a little research on *constructive receipt* and came across this gem of an article: http://www.bizer.com/lottery/. Seems like he may have an ax to grind, but there is quite a bit of good information, and leads me to believe that @Brick is probably right regarding finding a lawyer to defend either side. Though according to him the courts have currently always ruled that the money is taxable when **received**.

Comment: @TTT The "gem of an article" is based on a very selective reading of the fine print. Remember the Shakespearean quote that "The devil can cite Scripture for his purpose."

Comment: @DilipSarwate - I agree it is very selective! (I think the article's author may agree with you on that too.) He admitted that his interpretation is in the minority of most tax professionals that he discussed this with.

Comment: @TTT I was joking about paying a lawyer to argue either side. A few past winners did do that, but now the law pretty much established by all three branches of government.  It's constructive receipt. If you somehow had some weird and fundamentally new sequence of events that made it hard to determine when constructive receipt occurred, I guess you could litigated it. Even though most of us will never win the lottery, there are multiple winners each year. The answer is pretty well established.

Comment: @TTT Regarding the article: The author has misrepresented at least two of the court cases that he mentioned. I'm not motivated to check the other two now. In Jombo, the issue was about installments. Jombo wanted to pay tax in the first year even though installments would be paid over many. That does not fit constructive receipt (as was in my answer) because the winner has no claim to the later installments until later years. The Thomas case isn't even about constructive receipt. It's about another doctrine, which the courts ruled does not apply.

Comment: To sue the IRS in Tax Court, it is necessary to first pay the tax that the IRS claims is due, or to challenge the IRS collection after it has garniisheed wages, seized bank accounts etc to collect what it claims is the tax due (because the taxpayer refused to pay). In Tax Court, the taxpayer is the plaintiff and must "prove his case beyond a reasonable doubt" to win while the IRS is presumptively correct. Long uphill road....

Comment: @DilipSarwate A challenge to the tax is a civil matter, not criminal. The standard of proof is lower than "reasonable doubt" - Something like "preponderance of the evidence." The point about burden of proof being on the taxpayer is right in this context, although there are other situations where it can shift to the IRS.

Comment: "The standard of proof is lower..."  Yes, of course. That's why I put what I said in quotes, the beyond a reasonable doubt being more familiar to most readers than preponderance of evidence.

Comment: @Brick - so has there ever been any ruling where even though money was received in the following year, the taxable year is actually the preceding year in which the lottery was won? I haven't found one yet, and I'm thinking this type of ruling would be necessary to prove your answer is correct.

Comment: @TTT I'm not aware of a case where that issue has been raise. That's no evidence either way. Read the decision in the case Paul v Commissioner though. Even though in that case, the court ruled on the facts that constructive receipt was in the following year, the reasoning is clear that constructive receipt does apply. It's a legal document, but it's pretty easy to read. Under different specific circumstances, the IRS could definitely use this as precedent for taxing in the year of the drawing even though the IRS lost the Paul case.

Comment: @Brick - I just read Paul v Commissioner, and this sentence sealed it for me: "The doctrine of constructive receipt is a legal concept based on the principle that a taxpayer may not deliberately turn his back on income and thereby manipulate the proper year in which to report it." The OP, as currently stated in its contrived form, is certainly deliberately manipulating the tax year, and so this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The tax year will be determined by the date on the check from Lottery and they will withhold estimated taxes for federal, and for most state, incomes taxes.

Just remember if the ticket is claimed in January, then you will have to wait until the following year to get any possible refund.

Comment: This is incorrect. If the drawing took place in 2015 and there was enough time for the OP to submit the lottery ticket in 2015 for verification and payout, then delaying submitting the ticket for verification till 2016 does not convert the winnings into 2016 income. There was an extensive discussion of this matter on the Usenet group misc.taxes.moderated (now available on groups.google.com) some years ago. Lots depends on the exact facts, e.g. what if the Lottery office is closed on Saturday Dec 31 when the lottery results were announced on the 6 pm news on Friday 30th.

Comment: @Dilip, I think the jury is still out on whether or not this answer is correct. (See my comments to Brick's answer.) Regardless, the last sentence makes a good point, since large winnings typically have taxes withheld, if you are expecting a refund you may wish to choose to go out of your way to attempt to get the money in the current tax year.

Comment: The jury may still be out but for a lottery ticket bought on December 14 (presumably with the winners announced within the next few days), **wait for a few weeks and redeem the ticket after January 1** as the OP says is definitely deliberately delaying receipt of winnings, and not going to pass muster. Note also that it is the Tax Court judge who makes the decision, not a jury, and so is unlikely to be swayed by weepy tales of "my kids were sick and the dog died and my wife left me, and so I couldn't submit my ticket till after January 1.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - Haha! I think you're right if the winner is upfront about the delay. But realistically if someone did this they would not admit it, and it would be difficult to disprove that they simply didn't realize they had won until weeks later. Furthermore, if the article I sited in the other answer's comment is correct, there are 4 cases of people wanting constructive receipt to mean the year they won (I'm guessing because they were expecting refunds), but the IRS wanted constructive receipt to mean the year they received the money, and the courts sided with the IRS.

Comment: To followup on my last comment, maybe the lesson here is simply: Regardless of what you choose to do, the IRS gets to decide if they agree with your choice, and if they disagree, the courts will probably side with the IRS rather than you.

Comment: @TTT The reason this answer is wrong is that the date on the check is determined in part by when you submit ticket. If they write the check in January because they have some 30 day processing period, then the check *and the fact about the processing time* will be evidence that you did *not* have constructive receipt until January. If they're prepared to pay on demand and you do not present as soon as you can, then the date on the check means nothing. Sick, traveling, etc. will not impact the determination of constructive receipt. That's the difference between constructive and actual receipt.

Comment: @TTT See my comment on my answer about these court cases. I checked two and they do not support your point. The details matter. In one, constructive receipt was consistently applied and just happened to mean the year that the money was actually received. In the other, the case was not about constructive receipt at all. DIdn't check the other two, but your source misrepresented the facts. Also, your source created the same false dilemma as your question: The rule does not favor year or drawing or year of payment. It's a third choice that's a bit more subtle.

Answer (score -1):

Winnings are taxed in the year you receive payment.  Period.  Constructive requires an unqualified right to receive immediate payment.  One qualification is that lottery tickets must be verified.  Large winners usually have to wait a day or two, which voids the "immediate payment" clause.  Here's an extreme example:  If you don't cash the ticket until July after you've already filed your income taxes, is the state going to issue a retroactive W2G?  That's kinda hard when the IRS requires that tax reporting be received by January 31st.  Which year do you get to deduct the state income taxes paid/withheld?

Benton